# Creating tables in LDoc?

Tags: lua, markdown

How do I generate tables with LDoc and lua-discount?
Do I need some special configuration or version?

I am using LDoc to generate documentation for a game written in Lua. It works for the most part, but it uses markdown.lua which does not support markdown tables by default. So I switched it over to use lua-discount. But it still does not generate tables.

- The LDoc documentation does specify that I can use lua-discount and that it provides support for tables.
- I tried using an example table to isolate the problem.
- Calling lua-discount directly with the table yields the same result.
- Both LDoc and lua-discount were installed using luarocks without any version number.
- I tried switching to lunamark but forgot to install it, so it defaulted back to lua-discount. So I know it is detecting lua-discount.

My LDoc configuration:

```
title='A game'
readme='manuals'
format='discount'
file={ 'src', 'tests', 'library/library/library.c' }
dir='docs'
no_summary=true
kind_names={ topic='Manuals', module='API' }
```

I place markdown files in the manuals folder. To test, I took the table from the PHP markdown documentation (https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/), which lua-discount is supposed to support, and placed it in its own file with blank lines above and below it:

```
First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Content Cell  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | Content Cell
```

It generated:

```
    First Header  | Second Header
——————– | ——————–
Content Cell  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | Content Cell
```

But should generate:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>First Header</th>
  <th>Second Header</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Content Cell</td>
  <td>Content Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Content Cell</td>
  <td>Content Cell</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was directed to discord.gg/code for help, and someone there noticed I was using discount differently to what was documented. It turns out there are 2 completely different versions of lua-discount! http://asbradbury.org/projects/lua-discount/ (the version from luarocks) and https://github.com/craigbarnes/lua-discount.

The version on luarocks is either outdated, or never actually had support for tables.

So to fix this problem, I had to:

- Download a forked version of the repository that uses CMake (https://github.com/squeek502/lua-discount).
- Add discount to the empty discount folder.
- Set LUA_DIR.
- Make lua-discount (worked with Visual Studio 2019 Command Prompt).
- Copy the release dll to luarocks.
- Delete discount, which was installed to Program Files.